# setlocale to fr-FR in PHP and number formatting

Tags: php, locale, number-formatting

I am trying to create a French version of one of my sites. I have set `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR');` at the top of my page, and using `strftime` I am displaying dates correctly in the French style.

However I am having some problems with a number. Part of the page uses data I am getting from a Web Service. I am assigning a returned value to a var like this:

```
$overallRating = $returnArray['Overall'];
```

I am then using the following code later to format it to 1 decimal place

```
number_format($overallRating,1)
```

In the English version the overallRating value might be `7.5` and returns a value such as `7.5` (the reason for running it through the number_format is if it returns `7` I want it to display `7.0`)

However in the French version if I print out the raw $overallRating value I get `7,5` which looks like it has translated it into french. This would be fine but if I run it through `number_format` I get the error:

```
Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in /sites/index.php  on line 250
```

Line 250 is the `number_format` line

I presume the translation to `7,5` is messing it up, but not sure how to solve this...

Using PHP 5.3 in case there is anything new that helps me

Comment: This sounds like your value gets number_formatted somewhere else. Are you 100% sure that doesn't happen? Can you trace step by step at which point the value gets converted?

Comment: Although I am not number_formating the number before this I think the `setlocale` is translating it, as I said in the question if I print out the $overallRating in the French page before running it through number_format it is showing 7,5 (with a comma). I presume this is causing number_format to fail?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So eventually found the answer after a lot of research.

PHP only really works with standard US decimal seperators and can't cope with the french , seperator.

The answer, although not perfect is to reset numeric values to use US while allowing dates etc to be formatted in French. Placing this line:

```
 setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'C');
```

Under

```
 setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR');
```

has done the trick

Answer (score 1):

is this what you are asking ?

```
<?php
    $overallRating = number_format($number, 1, '.', '');
?>
```

Later Edit:

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR');
$number = '7';
echo $overallRating = number_format($number, 1, '.', '');
?>
```

Comment: Try putting a decimal in the number, that seems to be the problem. ie 7.5 instead of 7

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to take a French-edited string like "54,33" and save it back to the db as en_US number because, as has been pointed out, PHP really only likes numbers in the en_US format. I didn't see any built-in PHP conversion functions so built this to do the job. Removes the thousands separator and replaces the decimal separator with "." and it's designed to work with any setup.

```
//Currency Conversion Back to US for DB Storage or PHP number formatting
function number_convert_us($num) {
    $locale_settings = localeconv();
    $num = str_replace($locale_settings['mon_thousands_sep'], "", trim($num));
    $num = str_replace($locale_settings['mon_decimal_point'], ".", $num);
    return number_format((double)$num, 2, '.', '');
}
```

I'll build a similar thing for JavaScript. Found this library for display: http://software.dzhuvinov.com/jsworld-currency-formatting.html