# number format based on user culture php

Tags: php, currentuiculture

I am using php. I am trying to format a number based on the user culture.
what I ideally would love would be a function to which I could give the culture and the number as parameters and it would automatically format the number based on the culture but I have not found anything like that.

So I tried using setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, myCulture), then call localeconv() to know which decimal separator and thousands separator etc to use the number_format function.
I put results on variables, and they are all the same!
i.e. I made:

```
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "en-US");
$result1 = localeconv();
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "fr-FR");
$result2 = localeconv();
```

$result1 and $result2 are the exact same things!
What am I doing wrong? any idea? 
Thank you for your help,

Martin

Comment: What do the calls to `setlocale` return?

Comment: This will not work on Windows-based systems..

Comment: check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906326/setlocale-to-fr-fr-in-php-and-number-formatting

Comment: I tried what he said, the point is that setlocale() returns 0. And I wanna do the contrary of what he is trying to, convert an us formatted number to user culture formatted number. Result is still the same: us format number

Answer (score 1):

check the return value of `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "en-US");`

```
$val = setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "en-US");
if ($val === FALSE) //locale is not available
```

if the $val is returning FALSE for linux distributions run the following command

`locale-gen fr_FR.utf8` and it should install the locale for you.

Comment: indeed, it returns 0... I can't see why. I am using the 5.4 version of php. Are there any settings to do ??

Comment: `locale -a` type that in the server and see what u get. in the command line