# json_decode reformatting decimals in JSON based on locale

Tags: php, wordpress, localization, json

I'm currently working on a site that's localized in a couple of languages and I'm running into a problem where json_decode is reformatting decimals in JSON strings depending on the locale. When the locale is set to "en" the decimals remain untouched. However, in the "fr_FR" locale they get changed to "13,3" for example.

Source JSON:

```
{"debug":[{"id":13.3}]}
```

Output for "en"

```
Array
(
    [debug] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 13.3
                )
        )
    )
```

Output for "fr_FR"

```
Array
(
    [debug] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 13,3
                )
        )
    )
```

Is there any reason json_decode does this? Is there a way to prevent it?

The bug is causing problems with the Gravity Forms Wordpress plugin, but I've already isolated the problem to the json_decode function.

Comment: PHP formats those floats on *output*, `json_decode` has nothing to do with it I believe. Does that make it better?

Comment: Possible duplicates - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906326/setlocale-to-fr-fr-in-php-and-number-formatting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the issue is with how PHP handles numeric values. json_decode is simply transforming 13.3 to a float, which on output or being converted to a string is the localized "13,3". However, PHP does not deal well with localized number formats.

As per this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906326/setlocale-to-fr-fr-in-php-and-number-formatting), using setlocale has resolved the issue (for the most part)

```
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'C');
```